# When to allow red kuri squash to start to produce fruit

Tags: pumpkins, squash

I am growing red kuri squash in pots on my balcony. The pots I have chosen are definitely smaller than ideal, but they are growing pretty fast and have been since I put them out there in early April, but not at the rate that I usually see in videos online when people grow them directly in the ground.

Since then I have been aggressively picking off all flowers in an attempt to get their vines longer, since I was concerned about by subompitmal choice of pot.

But now I am thinking that I should start letting them flower and fertilizing them, even though they are probably only about a meter tall. How long does it typically take for a fruit to go from fertilized to harvest-ready?